# No linenumbers inside the multicolumn text

Tags: line-numbering, lineno

Good Evening,

I need to remove linenumbers from inside the multi-column text.

**Source:**

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
                \begin{enumerate}[\rm(a)]
                        \item Item 1
                        \item Item 2
                        \item Item 3
                        \item Item 4
                \end{enumerate}
        \end{multicols}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Required output:**

Need to remove line number 443 and 444

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: \rm it is also an old command.

Answer (score 2):

Line numbering may be suspended locally by issuing a `\nolinenumbers` directive inside a TeX group. Be sure to provide par breaks, either by issuing a `\par` directive or by providing an all-blank line, before the `\begingroup` as well as before the `\endgroup` statement.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,enumitem,lineno}
\begin{document}
\itshape
\linenumbers[441] % '[441]' is optional
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textnormal{(\alph*)},left=0pt,nosep]
      \item Item 1
      \item Item 2
      \par % <-- provide a par break
      \begingroup
      \nolinenumbers
      \item Item 3
      \item Item 4
      \par % <-- provide another par break
      \endgroup
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols} 
\end{document}
```